# PHP Laravel executing many ajax request at same time will give a 'encryption key' server error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Please help me with this simple PHP ajax requests issue since it is blocking me for a long time for my project.

Sending many (like 100) ajax GET requests to the PHP controller at same time will give a 'No application encryption key has been specified.' error. 
In Laravel, I created the following router:

```
<?php
Route::get('/database/abc/load_single/{elementId}','abcController@loadSingle');
```

and the abcController is defined as:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class abcController extends Controller{
    public function loadSingle($elementId){
        return 'abc';
    }
}
```

Then in the browser, I send an ajax GET request 100 times at the same time:

```
for (var index=0; index<100; index++){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlPrefix + "database/abc/load_single/10001",
    });
}
```

And the output results are not stable, I got 5 (it varies) out of 100 with server error. In the log file it says:

```
   [2017-11-18 10:31:53] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php(1035): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(46): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(24): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(749): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array)
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(721): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(885): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter')
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(813): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(780): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(721): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(215): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(189): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\public\\index.php(60): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse))
#16 {main}
"} 
[2017-11-18 10:34:11] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php(1035): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(46): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(24): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(749): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array)
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(721): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(885): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter')
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(813): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(780): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(721): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(138): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(647): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(622): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(588): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(577): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blank\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 {main}
"}
```

There should be some config I missed for this issue.
Please help me this issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make sure you have `APP_KEY` set with your `.env` file.

Now, if you have it really set, try running `php artisan config:cache` to cache configuration. Also in case you are using `APP_KEY` directly in your app make sure you are using corresponding config key instead.

Comment: Hi Marcin, your answer (well, after 5 mins) fixed my issue amazingly (I already spend a whole day trying to fix it), although I still don't know why it has fixed it. But many thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

if new created key in .env file via

```
php artisan key:generate
```

didn't help, then you should clear your cache and make new cache for your laravel configs via

```
php artisan config:cache
```

don't forget to restart apache / nginx after changes in configs.