# Testing Laravel with jMeter.. Error reading config

Tags: php, laravel, jmeter, laravel-5.5, jmeter-3.2

I´m trying to run a performance test in a simple web developed with Laravel 5.5 as backend.

It´s a simple test, only one sample getting the home page. When the test begins, all works correctly, but earlier or later, randomly, the request gets Error 500. No matters the concurrent users, ocurrs with 2 or 10 users.

This is the plan used: [jMeter Laravel-Core Simple Request JMX](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbltoazexfit4i9/laravel-core.jmx?dl=0)

- Download jMeter 3.13
- File > Open > Select jmx
- Configure the User Defined Variables
- Run test

Screenshot with a fail example with 5 users.
[image: Fail with 5 users]

Reviewing the laravel.log, the error is:

```
[2017-11-21 14:38:16] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1035): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(46): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
#2 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(24): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
#3 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(749): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#4 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array)
#6 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(732): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#7 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(885): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter')
#8 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(813): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(779): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#10 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#11 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#12 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(732): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#13 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(138): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#14 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(660): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#17 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(601): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#19 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(590): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(58): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#42 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 {main}
"}
[2017-11-21 14:38:16] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1035): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(46): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
#2 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(24): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
#3 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(749): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#4 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array)
#6 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(732): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#7 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(885): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter')
#8 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(813): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(779): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#10 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#11 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#12 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(732): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#13 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(215): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#14 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(189): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#15 /opt/http-2.4.12_2/htdocs/laravel-web/public/index.php(60): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#16 {main}
"}
```

In my `.env` file, I have `APP_ENV=local` not `APP_ENV=production` and the `APP_KEY` is set correctly (all earlier requests load correctly). I tried setting `APP_ENV=production`, but the problem persist...

In other laravel project tested, the error is:

```
[2017-11-20 16:19:37] production.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge' in C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'forge', '', Array)
#1 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(116): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'forge', '', Array)
#2 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(56): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=loca...', 'forge', '', Array)
#3 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=loca...', Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php(61): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
#6 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(956): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#7 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(824): Illuminate\Database\Connection->getPdo()
#8 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(709): Illuminate\Database\Connection->reconnectIfMissingConnection()
#9 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(351): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select column_n...', Array, Object(Closure))
#10 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder.php(38): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select column_n...', Array)
#11 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(238): Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder->getColumnListing('settings')
#12 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\backpack\settings\src\SettingsServiceProvider.php(29): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('getColumnListin...', Array)
#13 [internal function]: Backpack\Settings\SettingsServiceProvider->boot()
#14 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(759): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#16 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(742): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(Backpack\Settings\SettingsServiceProvider))
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Backpack\Settings\SettingsServiceProvider), 25)
#18 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(743): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#19 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#20 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#21 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(253): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#22 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap()
#23 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 {main}

Next Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge' in C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(116): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'forge', '', Array)
#1 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(56): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=loca...', 'forge', '', Array)
#2 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=loca...', Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php(61): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
#5 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(956): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#6 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(824): Illuminate\Database\Connection->getPdo()
#7 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(709): Illuminate\Database\Connection->reconnectIfMissingConnection()
#8 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(351): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select column_n...', Array, Object(Closure))
#9 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder.php(38): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select column_n...', Array)
#10 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(238): Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder->getColumnListing('settings')
#11 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\backpack\settings\src\SettingsServiceProvider.php(29): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('getColumnListin...', Array)
#12 [internal function]: Backpack\Settings\SettingsServiceProvider->boot()
#13 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(759): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#15 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(742): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(Backpack\Settings\SettingsServiceProvider))
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Backpack\Settings\SettingsServiceProvider), 25)
#17 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(743): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#18 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#19 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#20 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(253): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#21 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap()
#22 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 C:\xampp_7.0.9\htdocs\backpack-demo\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 {main}
```

So, I think, the problem it´s that sometimes, the config read fails and get the default values especifies in the config/app.php.

Has anyone had this problem or can test a Laravel project with the jmx provided?

Thanks!

Comment: have you check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-do-i-get-this-error?page=1 ? or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365198/php-laravel-executing-many-ajax-request-at-same-time-will-give-a-encryption-key ?

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for your comment. The second link did the trick and all works prefectly now...

If you can mark as solution, post as answer and I´ll check as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [laravel configuration issue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0):

You need to execute `php artisan config:cache` command. and check env configuration.

> Add an env configuration option to your app.php configuration file that looks like the following:

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
```

> **Caching And Env**
>
> If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.
>
> If you are calling `env`from within your application, it is strongly recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration files and call `env` from that location instead, allowing you to convert your `env` calls to `config` calls.